# New ceiling fan not working from wall switch

Tags: electrical

Trying to replace an old ceiling fan. Old fan had black wire, always hot, powering light (light controled with pull string on fan). Red wire, connected to fan unit (blue wire), controlled by wall switch. In other rooms of the house I had the same set up. New fan has a remote so it only has one live, one neutral, one ground coming in. In other rooms I capped the black, and conncted the red (wall switched) wire to black at the fan - and it works as expected in the other rooms.. switch powers up the red wire which powers the fan. I tried this same setup, but my wall switch does nothing - no power to the fan, now power ever registering at the red wire in the ceiling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pictures of the fan wires and the switch wires will help.  You need always hot either at the fan or switch.  If the black was always hot/power from the panel, then capping it stops power.  Wiring it correctly is what we need to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Solved... I figured it didn't make sense. The red wire was broken right where it entered the junction box. Was able to pull slack wire it as I stated and all worked. 3 hours later... :(